# DeepDiff on Nested JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary, deep-diff

I would like to find the difference between two JSON but, when I try to use the DeepDiff method it finds nothing.

```
from deepdiff import DeepDiff

item1 = {
    '__PythonResult__Modules': {
        'b': {
            'c': 
            ['foo']
        }
    }
}
item2 = {
    "__PythonResult__Modules" : {
        "global" : {
            "views" : {
                "from_python" :  {
                    "QDjl" : ["llll"]
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
DeepDiff(item1, item2)
```

I use Python 3.8 and DeepDiff 5.5.0.
Do you have an idea ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default DeepDiff ignores private variables. These are field names that start with double underscore.

You can test this by adding a letter to the start of the underscore.

Anyway to preform comparison, simply set the parameter `ignore_private_variables` to `False`

**That is:**

```
print(DeepDiff(item1, item2, ignore_private_variables=False))
```

**Output:**

```
{'dictionary_item_added': [root['__PythonResult__Modules']['global']], 'dictionary_item_removed': [root['__PythonResult__Modules']['b']]}
```

Comment: Too GOOOOOOOOOOD, a subtle tip yet helps a lot!!